# How to implement CP decomposition in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement Canonical Polyadic (CP) Decomposition for a Conv2D layer in Keras.
I found this [link](https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-tensor-decompositions/blob/master/decompositions.py) that has implemented it in PyTorch. Based on this, they have replaced a Conv2D layer with four Conv2D in sequence that based on this [link](https://jacobgil.github.io/deeplearning/tensor-decompositions-deep-learning) the middle layers are depthwise separable convolution. In the pytorch implementation they have used **groups** option of Conv2D layer to implement this.

I wanted to know if the **groups** option in pytorch and keras is exactly the same?
if not, how can I implement the behavior in Keras?